# zsh: killed python3.7 -m virtualenv ven error

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.7

Downloaded Python 3.7 and installed it on mac. Whenever trying to create virtualenv:

1. Command on mac terminal: python3.7 -m virtualenv venv
   Getting the following error:
   zsh: killed     python3.7 -m virtualenv venv
2. and when using following the command: virtualenv -p python3.7 venv
   Get the following error:
   RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7'

Installation location:
which python3.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7